# iverilog errors likely stemming from incorrect variable types

Tags: verilog, iverilog

I am new to verilog programming and am working on implementing an 8-bit unsigned magnitude comparator using 2 4 bit comparators. I believe my code is implemented correctly, however I am recieving errors which I believe are due to incorrect variable type assignments. As I am new to the language, I consider this a learning opportunity, however I cannot find enough relevant material to lead me to a solution. If someone could explain why the types I am using are incorrect (or if it is a different problem I am facing) it would be much appreciated.

EDIT: I changed my answer to that suggested, with module instantiation outside of the always block and wires as eq, gt, and lt, but am still getting errors. Updated the error code.

```
module MagComp4Bit (input [3:0] a, input [3:0] b, output eq, output gt, output lt);

    assign eq = a==b;
    assign gt = a>b;
    assign lt = a<b;

endmodule

module MagComp8Bit (input [7:0] a, input [7:0] b, output eq, output gt, output lt);

    reg eq0, gt0, lt0, eq1, gt1, lt1;

    MagComp4Bit comp1(a[3:0], b[3:0], eq0, gt0, lt0);
    MagComp4Bit comp2(a[7:4], b[7:4], eq1, gt1, lt1);
    always @(a, b)
    begin


            if (eq1) begin
                    eq = eq0? 1 : 0;
                    gt = gt0? 1 : 0;
                    lt = lt0? 1 : 0;
            end
            else begin
                    gt = gt1? 1 : 0;
                    lt = lt1? 1 : 0;
            end
    end
endmodule

module TestComparator;
    reg[7:0] a, b;
    wire eq, gt, lt;

    MagComp8Bit compare(a, b, eq, gt, lt);

    initial begin
            $moniter("%d a=%b, b=%b, eq=%b, gt=%b, lt=%b",
                    $time, a, b, eq, gt, lt);

            #10     a = 2;
                    b = 5;
    end
endmodule
```

error message:

```
hw1p1.v:13: error: reg eq0; cannot be driven by primitives or continuous 
assignment.
hw1p1.v:13: error: Output port expression must support continuous 
assignment.
hw1p1.v:13:      : Port 3 (eq) of MagComp4Bit is connected to eq0
hw1p1.v:13: error: reg gt0; cannot be driven by primitives or continuous 
assignment.
hw1p1.v:13: error: Output port expression must support continuous 
assignment.
hw1p1.v:13:      : Port 4 (gt) of MagComp4Bit is connected to gt0
hw1p1.v:13: error: reg lt0; cannot be driven by primitives or continuous 
assignment.
hw1p1.v:13: error: Output port expression must support continuous 
assignment.
hw1p1.v:13:      : Port 5 (lt) of MagComp4Bit is connected to lt0
hw1p1.v:14: error: reg eq1; cannot be driven by primitives or continuous 
assignment.
hw1p1.v:14: error: Output port expression must support continuous 
assignment.
hw1p1.v:14:      : Port 3 (eq) of MagComp4Bit is connected to eq1
hw1p1.v:14: error: reg gt1; cannot be driven by primitives or continuous 
assignment.
hw1p1.v:14: error: Output port expression must support continuous 
assignment.
hw1p1.v:14:      : Port 4 (gt) of MagComp4Bit is connected to gt1
hw1p1.v:14: error: reg lt1; cannot be driven by primitives or continuous 
assignment.
hw1p1.v:14: error: Output port expression must support continuous 
assignment.
hw1p1.v:14:      : Port 5 (lt) of MagComp4Bit is connected to lt1
hw1p1.v:22: error: eq is not a valid l-value in TestComparator.compare.
hw1p1.v:9:      : eq is declared here as wire.
hw1p1.v:23: error: gt is not a valid l-value in TestComparator.compare.
hw1p1.v:9:      : gt is declared here as wire.
hw1p1.v:24: error: lt is not a valid l-value in TestComparator.compare.
hw1p1.v:9:      : lt is declared here as wire.
hw1p1.v:27: error: gt is not a valid l-value in TestComparator.compare.
hw1p1.v:9:      : gt is declared here as wire.
hw1p1.v:28: error: lt is not a valid l-value in TestComparator.compare.
hw1p1.v:9:      : lt is declared here as wire.
17 error(s) during elaboration.
```

(P.S. I am aware it is improper to include a test bench with other modules, but it is easier for me to learn when I can see it all at once.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Verilog modules are not intended to be instantiated inside of initial or always blocks. That is why you should move:

```
MagComp4Bit(a[3:0], b[3:0], eq0, gt0, lt0);
MagComp4Bit(a[7:4], b[7:4], eq1, gt1, lt1);
```

outside `always` block. What is more, `eq, gt, lt` should be declared as wires in your TestComparator module.

Comment: Made these changes and still getting some similar errors.

Answer (score 0):

`wire` type cannot be assigned in any procedural block (always, intial, ..). You are doing jus that inside of the `always`

```
always...  
    .. 
    eq = eq0? 1 : 0;
```

where `eq` is defined as a port without any data type, which means `wire` by default. same about other 2 ports: `lt` and `gt`.

You need to change your code a bit:

```
reg eqReg, ltReg, wrReg;

always @(a, b)
    begin

        if (eq1) begin
                eqReg = eq0? 1 : 0;
                gtReg = gt0? 1 : 0;
                ltReg = lt0? 1 : 0;
        end
        else begin
                gtReg = gt1? 1 : 0;
                ltReg = lt1? 1 : 0;
        end
end
assign eq = eqReg;
assign lt = ltReg;
assign gt = gtReg;
```